# Телеграмм бот поддержки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

В общем, у меня есть бот поддержки, где можно оставить отзыв и сделать заказ. Если товара нет, то администратор из чата поддержки отвечает на сообщение через reply. Дело в том, что функции прекрасно работают, кроме последней, где сообщения, вызванные через кнопки должны обрабатываться. Если я ставлю последнюю функцию перед командой заказ, то у меня не работают команды. В общем и целом, если ставить выше функцию soo, то она ломает все команды. Что мне сделать, чтобы код работал как надо?

````
def start(massage):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Сделать заказ")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Оставить отзыв")
    markup.add(btn1,btn2)
    msg = bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, f"Текст", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["заказ"])
def order(m, res=False):
   global help_user_id
   help_user_id = m.from_user.id
   msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f"Текст")
   bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["отзыв"])
def feedback(m, res=False):
    global help_user_id
    help_user_id = m.from_user.id
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Текст")
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(m):
   if int(m.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID):
        global help_user_id
        help_user_id = m.from_user.id
        bot.send_message(help_user_id, m.text)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def soo(massage):
    if massage.text.lower() == "сделать заказ":
        bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, f"Для заказа отправьте подробно заполненную анкету добавив перед ней /заказ")
    elif massage.text.lower() == "оставить отзыв":
        bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, f"Что бы оставить отзыв, пришлите его в чат, добавив перед ним /отзыв")
    else:
        bot.forward_message(got, massage.chat.id, massage.message_id)

bot.infinity_polling()```
````

Comment: Когда вы создаете обработчики на проверку по типу `"text"`, то берется самый первый обработчик, игнорируя последующие подобные. Самое разумное решение - засунуть всё в один обработчик по тексту.

Comment: `TO_CHAT_ID` это целевой id канала, куда будут пересылаться уведомления и логи о том, что пользователь делает с ботом

Comment: `help_user_id` это id, полагаю, пользователя, которому требуется помощь по заказу

Comment: немного не понятно что за переменная `got` в последнем текстовом обработчике

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал ваш код, встроив код из `handler_text` в функцию `soo` как первое условие. Работает он следующим образом.

Пользователь 1 вызывает `/заказ` или `/отзыв` с текстом, далее бот отправляет ему `Текст`, а затем сообщение пересылается в `TO_CHAT_ID` поддержки. Далее, уже поддержка даёт ответ в виде простого сообщения, а бот данное сообщение печатает последнему пользователю сделавшим заказ или отзыв.

Ракурс пользователя

[image: Ракурс пользователя]

Ракурс поддержки

[image: Ракурс поддержки]

Недостатки при данном подходе очевидны, если поддержка не успеет ответить до момента, пока следующий пользователь не вызовет `/заказ` или `/отзыв`, то пользователю уже не получится отправить сообщение через бота, акцент переключится на следующего пользователя.

Тем не менее, вот исправленный код

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

# Initialize the bot with your API token
bot = telebot.TeleBot("<ваш API>")

TO_CHAT_ID = <ваш чат id поддержки>

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(massage):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Сделать заказ")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Оставить отзыв")
    markup.add(btn1,btn2)
    msg = bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, f"Текст", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["заказ"])
def order(m, res=False):
   global help_user_id
   help_user_id = m.from_user.id
   msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, f"Текст")
   bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)


@bot.message_handler(commands=["отзыв"])
def feedback(m, res=False):
    global help_user_id
    help_user_id = m.from_user.id
    msg = bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Текст")
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, m.chat.id, m.message_id)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def soo(massage):
    if int(massage.chat.id) == int(TO_CHAT_ID):
        global help_user_id
        bot.send_message(help_user_id, massage.text)
    elif massage.text.lower() == "сделать заказ":
        bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, f"Для заказа отправьте подробно заполненную анкету добавив перед ней /заказ")
    elif massage.text.lower() == "оставить отзыв":
        bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, f"Что бы оставить отзыв, пришлите его в чат, добавив перед ним /отзыв")
    else:
        bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, massage.chat.id, massage.message_id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

---

*p.s имхо, может стоит пересмотреть всё в **тикет архитектуру** с базой данных пользователей заказов и отзывов?*

Comment: Благодарю за вашу помощь! Вы мне очень помогли. Я обязательно спрошу у друга, которому писал бота, насчёт тикетов.

Comment: @verfer38 если требуется какая консультация, то можете обратится по адресу в моём профиле, удачи!